# How to display a multi-line title in a Highslide pop-up while using Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, highslide

I'm using Highcharts to display a chart and I'm using Highslide to display additional information in a pop-up when the user clicks on a point in the chart. However, I want to add additional information to the title/heading-text in the pop-up.

I've gotten Highslide to work in displaying basic information using the following code:

```
$(function () {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'line'
        }
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        }
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                                pageOrigin: {
                                    x: this.pageX,
                                    y: this.pageY
                                },
                                headingText: this.series.name,
                                maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) +':<br/> '+
                                    this.y +' visits',
                                width: 200
                            });
                        }
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            }
        },
        series: []
    }
});
```

I've read through the API for Highslide and saw that you could use the 'heading' variable with the 'Expander.prototype.onAfterGetHeading' function, which I've displayed below, but I'm not sure how to implement it with Highcharts.

```
hs.Expander.prototype.onAfterGetHeading = function () {
    this.heading.html = 'this.a.title';
}
```

[HERE](http://www.roadrash.no/hs-support/multiline-heading.html)'s a site that displays a pop-up with a multi-line title in a Highslide pop-up, as an example. However, keep in mind that I'm trying to implement this in Highcharts, possibly with dynamic text in the title.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a solution you can use with Highcharts: http://jsfiddle.net/roadrash/gd3xz/

Please note that this is the correct code to insert the anchor's title text in the heading, as an additional heading text:

```
hs.Expander.prototype.onAfterGetHeading = function (sender) {
    if (sender.heading) {
        sender.heading.innerHTML += this.a.title;
    }
};
```

I’m not familiar with Highcharts, but I don’t think you can use `this.a.title` since `a` refers to the anchor tag. You can of course insert something else than `this.a.title` with the above code, as I've done in my demo.